# Exporting to MySQL from Excel using "MySQL for Excel plugin" is very slow

Tags: mysql, excel, export, mysqlimport

I have data in excel sheet and have to export the data to MySQL. I am using the **MySQL for Excel** tool in **Data** tab to export the data to a new table.

[image: MySQL Tool for Excel]

I have a table with *id (primary key)* and *name (unique, with index)*, around 1000 rows. Exporting it takes 3 - 5 minutes.

Why is it so slow? Any suggestions or tips on how I can speed up the export process?
I have a sheet with 150,000 rows. So need some help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way to do it:

1. Create the table from excel using **MySQL plugin for Excel**. It can be done manually, make sure to have the same columns in the excel and the table (order and data type).
2. Before saving the sheet as a CSV, replace all **comma (,)** characters in the sheet with blank string; because the comma acts as separator for columns. Save the file as a **.csv** file.
3. Open **mysql command line tool** and run the below sql to import data to the table. Replace the csv file path and table name.

`LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/data.csv" INTO TABLE mytable COLUMNS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n";`

This imported 155,000 columns in a matter of seconds.